# vuetify :v-date-picker error on changing calendar type

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

to see error

1.switch `type` to `month`

2.select a **months range**

3.change `type` to `date`

then you will see this **error** :

[image]

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
  modal : false ,
  currentLocale : 'en',
  selectOptions : [
    { key: 'date', value: 'Date' },
    { key: 'month', value: 'Month' }
  ],
  calType : 'date',
  range : true,
  date : []
    }
  },
    methods: {
     selectType($event) {
       this.calType = $event;
     },
    },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
           <v-col cols="12">
          <v-select
            v-model="calType"
            label="select date type"
            item-text="value"
            item-value="key"
            :items="selectOptions"
            dense
            single-line
            v-on:change="selectType($event)"
          >
          </v-select>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-dialog
            ref="dialog"
            v-model="modal"
            :return-value.sync="date"
            persistent
            width="290px"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="date"
                label="Picker in dialog"
                prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                readonly
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker
              v-model="date"
              :locale="currentLocale"
              :range="range"
              :type="calType"
              :first-day-of-week="1"
              scrollable
            >
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal = false">
                Cancel
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.dialog.save(date)">
                OK
              </v-btn>
            </v-date-picker>
          </v-dialog>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

so, how can i **fix** this ?

[image]
[image]

also this is another photo

[image]

Comment: Which value do you see in your Vue devtools? Also, doesn't it need to be cleared at some point? A month and a data are probably not the same format, if you keep one on top of the other it will error, seems legit.

Comment: you can see , error on the snippet i provided above

Comment: and this error happens when you select range of dates and when date picker configured to select just on date , it works fine

Comment: Yep, my 2 points in my initial comment are still valid (vue's devtools actual state + probably clean the state to match what is attended here)

Comment: i Added Vuedev tools error pic

Comment: Please provide the state of the actual component with the data, not the error.

Comment: it is added . . .

Comment: @kissu i also added another photo of actual state before error